# NodeMCU v1.0 high power consumption in deepsleep

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu

I am using a NodeMCU v.1.0 ESP-12 for a small project. It is powered by 3xAA batteries (4.5v) in Vin, but to reduce power consumption I need to put in in deepsleep every now and then.

Running this small sketch:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(2000);

  // Wait for serial to initialize.
  while(!Serial) { }

  Serial.println("I'm awake.");

  Serial.println("Going into deep sleep for 20 seconds");
  ESP.deepSleep(20e6); // 20e6 is 20 seconds
}

void loop() {
}
```

I have measured a consumption of 8mA when it goes to deepsleep, and this is not acceptable for my purpose. In order to wake up from sleep I have connected pin GPIO16 (D0) to RST, and it works. I knew that NodeMCU should have only few µA of consumption in deepsleep. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the LED?

Comment: Which one? The board has just a tiny blu LED which flashes for a moment when you switch it on, then it turns off. No LEDs are on during operations.

Comment: Sorry forget the LED! Look at the LDO,  look at this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286249/replace-ams1117-5v-3-3v-ldo-on-nodemcu-for-lipo-with-low-quiescent-current

Comment: I will read that link, thanks. But I have also made a test powering it directly on the 3V3 pin by an external regulator and the results are the same.

Comment: I have read the article. So, you suggest me to remove the internal LDO and use an external MPC1700? I am not a soldering-meister, so I am afraid I will break the device...

Comment: how much is used by the usb serial that you don't need after flashing?

Comment: The usb serial is not used, after flashing. But I always have the opportunity to update the sketch!

Comment: The usb to serial still uses power, even when it isnt used.

Comment: Yes, I have replaced an LDO in a similar exercise with an Arduino UNO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the TI TPL5110 timer chip with power control MOSFET. Set the timer period with a resistor then the TPL5110 powers on the NodeMCU periodically. Deep sleep is not used. RTC RAM will be lost so use SPIFFS for persistent data.

Adafruit has a breakout board. Take a look in Adafruit's forum for user comments because it has a few limitations.

Comment: You worried me about your warning "look at comments..", but I can't find anything serious...